# Determining force of interaction from a decay equation

Tags: interactions, weak-interaction, exchange-interaction

I have the decay equation

$$p + π^− → n + K^− + π^+.$$

I have been told the force of interaction in this is the weak nuclear force, but I was looking for an explanation of how you can work that out having been only given the decay equation.

Comment: Look your reaction only involves force carrier particles of electroweak force, no gluons are involved, just try to make a Feynman diagram for it. If you're a beginner then just use a good book for studies, An intro to quantum field theory by Peskin and Schroeder or any other introductory book.

Comment: A proton can’t become a neutron unless an up quark becomes a down quark. What vertex changes an up quark to a down quark?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the quark content of the hadrons on either side of the equation.  On the left there are $uud+d\bar{u}$ for the proton and pion.  On the right, the daughter particles are $udd+s\bar{u}+u\bar{d}$. The difference between the two sides is a $s$ quark and a $\bar{d}$ antiquark, with a net change in strangeness of $\Delta S=1$.

There are no flavor-changing neutral currents (large enough to have been observed) in the standard model.  The only interactions that can change strangeness by a single unit (as opposed to creating a $s$-$\bar{s}$ pair, for which $\Delta S=0$) have to be mediated by $W^{\pm}$ bosons.  So you can conclude that the process involved the weak interaction.